# How to unpack a dictionary of list (of dictionaries!) and return as grouped tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I have a data structure consisting of mixed dictionaries and lists. I am trying to unpack this so as to get tuples of the keys and all sub-values for each key.

I am working with list comprehensions, but just not getting it to work. Where am I going wrong?

I saw many other answers about unpacking a list-of-lists (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586757/understanding-list-comprehension-for-flattening-list-of-lists-in-python),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399386/nested-lists-and-list-comprehensions)), but could not find an example where a single key unpacks against multiple sub-values.

- desired output --> [('A',1,2),('B',3,4)]
- actual output -->  [('A',1), ('A',2), ('B',3), ('B',4)]

code:

```
dict_of_lists = {'A':[{'x':1},{'x':2}], 'B':[{'x':3},{'x':4}] }
print [(key,subdict[subkey],) for key in dict_of_lists.keys() for subdict in dict_of_lists[key] for subkey in subdict.keys()]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When list comprehensions become

- long
- unclear/hard to read
- and most importantly, **do not work**

ditch them and go with the manual for loop(s) every time:

### Python 2.x

```
def unpack(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        tmp = []
        for subdict in v:
            for _, val in subdict.iteritems():
                tmp.append(val)
        yield (k, tmp[0], tmp[1])


print list(unpack({'A':[{'x':1},{'x':2}], 'B':[{'x':3},{'x':4}] }))
```

### Python 3.x

```
def unpack(d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            tmp = []
            for subdict in v:
                for _, val in subdict.items():
                    tmp.append(val)
            yield (k, *tmp) # stared expression used to unpack iterables were
                            # not created yet in Python 2.x                

print(list(unpack({'A':[{'x':1},{'x':2}], 'B':[{'x':3},{'x':4}] })))
```

**Output:**

```
[('A', 1, 2), ('B', 3, 4)]
```

Comment: thanks, I like this advice. But I am getting a syntax error on the `*` of `*tmp`

Comment: @Roberto Sorry. Didn't see you were using Python 2.x. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the list of dicts and get only the values. Then combine with the dict key.

```
>>> for k,L in dict_of_lists.iteritems():
...   print tuple( [k]+[v for d in L for v in d.values()])

('A', 1, 2)
('B', 3, 4)
```

If you need a one liner:

```
>>> map(tuple, ([k]+[v for d in L for v in d.values()] for k,L in dict_of_lists.iteritems()))

[('A', 1, 2), ('B', 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand the syntax better, and why I was not getting it to work in the first place.